# Is it possible to set a default preview mode in TYPO3 4.7?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

Is there any way to configure which [preview mode (slider, horizontal, vertical)](http://www.ndsu.edu/cms/kb/preview/) is used as the default preview mode for the workspace preview, called from the *workspace preview link*?

After upgrading to TYPO3 4.7 the default mode was set to slider, which is quite buggy in some browsers. Therefore we would like to set another default.

Comment: I am not sure what you are referring to. Do you mean a slider in the frontend?

Comment: When using workspaces, there is a slider that let you compare live version with dev version. It overlays the changes.

Comment: I mean the slider in the page preview, as described [here](http://www.ndsu.edu/cms/kb/preview/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to set this successfully, but try to fiddle around with this value in your [page TSConfig](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TSconfigReference/PageTsconfig/Field/Index.html):

```
workspaces.workspaces.splitPreviewModes.value = vbox, hbox
```

or

```
tx_workspaces.workspaces.splitPreviewModes.value = vbox, hbox
```

Default value is `slider, vbox, hbox`. IMHO you can only remove the slider, but not set another mode as default.

---

If you know how to tame PHP code, check for exact rendering at the system file `typo3/sysext/workspaces/Classes/Controller/PreviewController.php` >  `$splitPreviewModes`